# Display size is different for the same applications

Tags: android, size, screen, scale, display

I've made 2 same applications with different package id (AndroidManifest.xml). Package id is the the only difference!

First package id:  com.vlasovsoft.math (exists at Play Store)
Second package id: com.vlasovsoft.math1 (doesn't exists at Play Store)

The problem is:

the first application (com.vlasovsoft.math) reports me screen size 1440x900

while the second application reports me **true screen size** 1920x1200.

What's the problem ?

My device is Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 2016

Code for displaying screen size:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
Snackbar.make(view, metrics.widthPixels + "x" + metrics.heightPixels, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
```

PS

This problem is not reproduced on my Samsung Galaxy J3 2016

Comment: Maybe this problem is related to google play maybe not... I've also tried device factory reset - no success!

Answer (score -1):

I know you can change the DPI on the j3 and developer settings it also helps out a lot so but I'm still at the j3 is is a tricky phone the demo mode is is what I don't understand

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to make any use of this answer.